# Improving Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

Giving a result, I need to do a match with the table, considering the priority, suppose the following table:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
+---+---+
|  0|  1|
+---+---+
```

Giving a results collection with two rows:

```
[[A => 1, B => 1], [A => 0, B => 1]]
```

or

```
[[A => 0, B => 1], [A => 1, B => 1]]
```

The result that match is `[A => 1, B => 1]`, because is the result that match with the first item of table.

The only way that I found is:

```
getMatchingResult (result) {
    first = null;
    second = null;
    third = null;

    //fill each case if exists
    foreach (result as r) {

       if (r.A && r.B) {
            first = r;
       }

       if (r.A && !r.B) {
            second = r;
       }

       if (!r.A && r.B) {
            third = r;
       }

    }

    //handle priority
    if (first)
        return first;
    else if (second)
        return second
    else if (third)
        return third;

    return false; 
}

getMatchingResult([[A => 0, B => 1], [A => 1, B => 1]]);
// [A => 1, B => 1]

getMatchingResult([[A => 1, B => 1], [A => 0, B => 1]]);
// [A => 1, B => 1]
```

Is there some better way do to this? Or is there some algorithm that work with these type of problems?

Thanks!

Comment: This algorithm terminates if there is a match or no match, during the very first iteration. I don't see how "priority" is handled. - Also, it's unclear what should match with those many A's and B's in a results collection row. Clarification, please.

Comment: thanks for help @laune, I fixed my wrong logic

Comment: [[A => 1, B => 1], [A => 0], [B => 1]] - what does this mean in relation to r.A and r.B? I don't understand what the last 4 lines are supposed to mean.

Comment: @laune I updated the code [[A => 0, B => 1], [A => 1, B => 1]] we can consider it as an array of objects, so the first is r1.A = 0, r1.B = 0, and the second r2.A = 1 and r2.B = 1, so we have an array of objects [r1, r2] is ok now? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values of r.A and r.B are booleans there's not much you can to improve the logic. But if the domain for r.A and r.B has more values and the table can grow, a sequential search for the pair with the smallest index (= highest priority) requires many comparisons. There are indeed ways to improve this.

Consider

```
class Pair { int a; int b; ... }
Map<Pair,Integer> pair2rank;
```

Here, the map provides for a lookup of a pair of values returning the rank in the table. The map is prepared initially from that table. The loop becomes then

```
int rank = pair2rank.size(); // bigger than any rank 0, 1,...
foreach (Pair p: results) {
    int rp = pair2rank.get( p );
    if( rp < rank ) rank = rp;
}
// rank contains the smallest table index
```